# Как конвертировать scrapy проект в exe

Tags: python, exe, конвертация, scrapy

Пробовал конвертировать PyInstaller, py2exe. В первом случае, при конвертации только паука(запускал его скриптом, не из cmd), exe файл получался, но не работал, пробовал директорию с проектом конвертировать, но была ошибка Permission denied(решения не нашел).
Во втором случае(py2exe) вообще ничего получилось, делал по документации.
Как посоветуете попробовать конвертировать и можно ли вообще такое сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller yourprogram.py
```

попробуй без указания каких либо аргументов, если неудачно, скинь код ошибки

Comment: Ошибок никаких не было, но и ожидаемого результата не было

Comment: А какого результата ты ожидаешь?

Comment: Парситься сайт, нужные данные сохраняются в csv файл